# How to prove independence of system of quadratic equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, problem-solving, quadratics

I hope you may be able to help me with my problem. I don't know if it is actually possible to do what I want to do, but maybe I overlooked an answer.

I have a system of quadratic equations

$ \begin {pmatrix}
y_1 \\ y_2 \\ y_3
 \end{pmatrix} 
=
A \cdot 
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3
\end{pmatrix} +
 B \cdot 
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1^2  \\ x_2^2  \\ x_3^2
\end{pmatrix} +
C\cdot 
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\cdot x_3  \\ x_2\cdot x_3  \\ x_1\cdot x_2
\end{pmatrix} $

The matrices A and B and the y vector are given. I have been solving the system of equations with matlab with a solve() function. I have been varying the values of $y_1, y_2$ and $y_3$, which has been working fine so far. However, I ran into problems when trying to solve the system for a certain value for $y_2 = y_3$.
It will work for other values and $y_2 = y_3$.

When I try to solve the equations for $y_3 = 0.99999999 \cdot y_2$ with $y_2$ being the problematic value, it will work just fine. I haven't figured out why this is the case. Therefore I wanted to check if the system is still solvable with  $y_2 = y_3$ by checking for independence.

Is there another way to check if it still solvable? Or might it be another problem, maybe the solver just not being able to solve it?

Thank you in advance! Your help is appreciated.

edit:

The values of the vectors and matrices are

$ \begin {pmatrix}
750 \\ 1500 \\ 1500
 \end{pmatrix} 
=
\begin {pmatrix}
500 & 0 & 0  \\  500 & 500 & 0  \\ 0 & 0 & 500
 \end{pmatrix}  \cdot 
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3
\end{pmatrix} +
\begin {pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0  \\  -19.581 & -15.053 & 0  \\ 0 & 0 & -15.053
 \end{pmatrix}  \cdot  
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1^2  \\ x_2^2  \\ x_3^2
\end{pmatrix} +
\begin {pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0  \\  11.32 & 11.32 & -34.634  \\ 11.32  & 11.32  & 0
 \end{pmatrix}  \cdot  
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\cdot x_3  \\ x_2\cdot x_3  \\ x_1\cdot x_2
\end{pmatrix}$

The problem arose while I was trying to calculate the currents required  for a certain power to be converterted at certain points in an asymmetrical electrical dc network. Basically I'm looking at a multiterminal bipolar HVDC network  in metallic return mode and an outage at one station.

What might need to be mentioned is that im using the solver of the symbolic toolbox of matlab.

Comment: There might not be a solution e.g. $x_1 = 1$ and $x_1 = 2$ does not have a solution. See what parameters/conditions/error message solve returns.

Comment: The solver doesn't return any warnings or errors. When I run the programm with the critical values for $y_2$ and $y_3$ it just returns wrong values. When I solve it symbolically it doesn't return any warings or errors either.

Comment: Add the values of A and B  and y to the question.

Comment: For the mixed terms, I would have expected the order to be $(x_2 x_3, x_3 x_1, x_1 x_2).$    What is the source of the problem?

Comment: I thought it the order of the elements in the vector didn't matter as it equals a summation of the elements multiplied with the matrix. Please correct me if I'm wrong on that.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/) the code and results are below:

```
E1 : -750 + 500*x1;
E2 : -1500 + 500*x1 + 500*x2 -19.581*x1^2 -15.053*x2^2 + 9.58*x1*x3 + 9.58*x2*x3 -34.634*x1*x2;
E3 : -1500 + 500*x3 -15.053*x3^2 + 9.58*x1*x3 + 9.58*x2*x3;

solve([E1,E2,E3],[x1,x2,x3]);

[x1 = 1.5, x2 = 85.96972563859981, x3 = 87.74766355140187], 
[x1 = 1.5, x2 = 29.27408993576017, x3 = 1.959984609465179], 
[x1 = 1.5, x2 = 1.655006858710562, x3 = 3.102202145680407], 
[x1 = 1.5, x2 = 0.4651535380507343, x3 = 31.2810650887574]
```

The results are not very accurate? Substituting each result back into the three equations:

```
           subst(R[1],[E1,E2,E3]);
    (%o13)        [0.0, 0.004048568953294307, - 0.007026502295047976]
    (%i14) subst(R[2],[E1,E2,E3]);
    (%o14)        [0.0, - 7.914470367040849e-4, 2.623238295029751e-6]
    (%i15) subst(R[3],[E1,E2,E3]);
    (%o15)        [0.0, - 1.355784513634717e-5, 1.001358072869607e-4]
    (%i16) subst(R[4],[E1,E2,E3]);
    (%o16)        [0.0, 1.999027597321401e-5, - 0.001041557330609066]
```

---

```
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-750+%2B+500*x1+%3D+0,+-1500+%2B+500*x1+%2B+500*x2+-19.581*x1%5E2+-15.053*x2%5E2+%2B+9.58*x1*x3+%2B+9.58*x2*x3+-34.634*x1*x+%3D+0,+-1500+%2B+500*x3+-15.053*x3%5E2+%2B+9.58*x1*x3+%2B+9.58*x2*x3
```

Wolfram gives:

```
x3 (9.58 x1+9.58 x2+500.)-15.053 x3^2-1500.≈-15.053 x3^2+500. x3-1500.
```

---

Using the grobner basis package in maxima:

```
load(affine);

grobner_basis([-750 + 500*x1,-1500 + 500*x1 + 500*x2 -19.581*x1^2 -15.053*x2^2 + 9.58*x1*x3 + 9.58*x2*x3 -34.634*x1*x2,-1500 + 500*x3 -15.053*x3^2 + 9.58*x1*x3 + 9.58*x2*x3]);
```

Gives:

$$\left(-576830960000000\right)\,{\it x_3}+\left(-
 5411710412472\right)\,{\it x_2}^3+643257403387460\,{\it x_2}^2+
 \left(-15004525334998746\right)\,{\it x_2}+24884658413238003 = 0$$

$$ \left(-10823420824944\right)\,{\it x_2}^4+1270279675537504\,
 {\it x_2}^3+\left(-29892020931835112\right)\,{\it x_2}^2+
 58711593597479768\,{\it x_2}+\left(-20969575034285991\right) = 0$$

$$ \left(-2\right)\,{\it x_1}+3 = 0$$

The third equation gives $x_1 = 1.5$.

The second equation gives a fourth order polynomial in $x_2$.

The first equation is linear in $x_3$ and cubic in $x_2$.

So solve for $x_2$ then substitute into the first equation to find $x_3$.

```
plot2d(R[2],[x2,-20,100]);
```

[image]

This is what the second equation ($x_2^4$) looks like.

[image]

Notice that it rises from zero to approx. $1e16$ very quickly.

You may require higher floating point precision to get accurate answers.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I noticed that I gave you the wrong value for one of the parameters. It's 11.32 instead of 9.58 ( The original value given was 283/25 and I somehow miscalculated). However I took your maxima code and solved the equations with the correct value. The result in maxima is the same as it is with Matlab when I use 1500.000001 instead of 1500.

Comment: The Maxima code I used is:E1 : `-750 + 500*x1;
E2 : -1500 + 500*x1 + 500*x2 -19.581*x1^2 -15.053*x2^2 + 283/25*x1*x3 + 283/25*x2*x3 -34.634*x1*x2;
E3 : -1500 + 500*x3 -15.053*x3^2 + 283/25*x1*x3 + 283/25*x2*x3;

solve([E1,E2,E3],[x1,x2,x3]);` The results are: `[[x1=1.5,x2=128.3092105263158,x3=130.067615658363],[x1=1.5,
x2=29.41272189349112,x3=1.823754789272031],[x1=1.5,x2=
1.618653629183904,x3=3.066596194503171],[x1=1.5,x2=0.3262285375962108
,x3=31.41758793969849]]`

Comment: The Matlab code I used the calculate the results are:`syms Idpos1 Idpos2 Idneg
eqn1= 500*Idpos1 == 750;
eqn2 = (Idpos1 + Idpos2)*(283/25*Idneg-19581/1000*Idpos1-15053/1000*Idpos2+500)==1500;
eqn3 = Idneg*(283/25*Idpos1-15053/1000*Idneg+283/25*Idpos2+500) == 1500;
sol = solve([eqn1, eqn2, eqn3],Idpos1, Idpos2, Idneg);
double(sol.Idpos1)
double(sol.Idpos2)
double(sol.Idneg)`

Comment: and I get the following results: `x1 =

    1.5000
    1.5000
    1.5000
    1.5000


x2 =

 -58.9756 +15.4073i
 -58.9756 -15.4073i
   2.0922 + 0.0000i
 -15.5194 + 0.0000i


x3 =

  -2.3057 - 4.9518i
  -2.3057 + 4.9518i
   3.0300 + 0.0000i
   5.9634 + 0.0000i`

Comment: As soon as I use 1500.00000001 (or any other value differing just a tiny bit) I get the same values as with maxima: `x1 =

    1.5000
    1.5000
    1.5000
    1.5000


x2 =

   1.0e+02 *

   0.2941 + 0.0000i
   0.0162 - 0.0000i
   0.0033 - 0.0000i
   1.2831 + 0.0000i


x3 =

   1.0e+02 *

   0.0182 - 0.0000i
   0.0307 + 0.0000i
   0.3142 - 0.0000i
   1.3007 - 0.0000i`

Comment: @Heribert Schnackenwurst : It is odd that your Maxima results are different. It would be interesting to see how accurately each result solves the three equations. try:

$$R : solve([E1,E2,E3],[x1,x2,x3]); $$
$$subst(R[1],[E1,E2,E3]); $$
$$subst(R[2],[E1,E2,E3]); $$
$$subst(R[3],[E1,E2,E3]); $$
$$subst(R[4],[E1,E2,E3]); $$

You expect all zeros.

Comment: The results are:`(%o7) [0.0,-0.007425658259307966,-0.002421329962089658]
(%o8) [0.0,-0.007425658259307966,-0.002421329962089658]
(%o9) [0.0,-3.086852855176403*10^-4,7.184639878232701*10^-5]
(%o10) [0.0,-3.086852855176403*10^-4,7.184639878232701*10^-5]
(%o11) [0.0,-3.246820104152448*10^-5,3.45977092308658*10^-5]
(%o12) [0.0,-3.246820104152448*10^-5,3.45977092308658*10^-5]
(%o13) [0.0,-2.129379265625175*10^-5,-7.040034870442469*10^-5]`

Comment: They all seem to be within an acceptable range.

Comment: @Heribert Schnackenwurst : You have to decide what the acceptable accuracy is.

Comment: As I wrote before, I iniatially gave you the wrong values. The values I used to calculate the results in maxima and in matlab are the same however, except for the variation of 1500.

Comment: @Heribert Schnackenwurst : I reran it with the correct data.

$$E1 : -750 + 500*x1;$$
$$E2 : -1500 + 500*x1 + 500*x2 -19.581*x1^2 -15.053*x2^2 + 283/25*x1*x3 + 283/25*x2*x3 -34.634*x1*x2;$$
$$E3 : -1500 + 500*x3 -15.053*x3^2 + 283/25*x1*x3 + 283/25*x2*x3;$$

$$R : solve([E1,E2,E3],[x1,x2,x3]);$$


 $$The results are:$$ 
 $$[x1=1.5,x2=128.3092105263158,x3=130.067615658363]$$
 $$[x1=1.5, x2=29.41272189349112,x3=1.823754789272031]$$
 $$[x1=1.5,x2= 1.618653629183904,x3=3.066596194503171]$$
 $$[x1=1.5,x2=0.3262285‌​375962108 ,x3=31.41758793969849]$$

Comment: @Heribert Schnackenwurst : in matlab plug the results back in to the equations and see how large the error is.

Comment: The results I get with matlab while using 1500 for $y_2$ are way off. I have no problem with the results being in a certain range +/- 0.01%. The problem is that with the results I get from matlab the equation system isn't met. When I used the results from matlab with $y_2 = 1500$ I get 2072 instead of 1500.

Comment: @Heribert Schnackenwurst :  its an "ill conditioned system of equations". The floating point resolution is not high enough to deal with cancellations in the algorithms used.

Comment: @Heribert Schnackenwurst : plugging the solution back into the equation is a good sanity check for non linear equation solutions.

Comment: So basically the system of equations is solvable but the algorithm the solver uses and the resolution makes the it unsolvable for the solve-function for certain input parameters?

Comment: My biggest problem at this point is, that I am trying to write a programm that will solve the system of equations for different input values of $y_1$, $y_2$ and $y_3$. For most of the parameter sets it will work just fine. I just ran into this phenomenon by accident and I was wondering why this kept happening. Maybe I'll just have to add some sort of result checker that automatically reruns the calculation with slightly modified input values.

Comment: @Heribert Schnackenwurst : Yes. That's why you need  sanity checks. You can search for "I'll conditioned matrix" to see that this occurs often enough that it has had considerable work done on it.

Comment: @Heribert Schnackenwurst : There is an excellent documentary called :High Anxieties- The Mathematics of Chaos (2008)  at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qfp5tKeSQAc Edward Norton Lorenz discovered this before you and called it The Butterfly Effect.

Comment: Thank you very much! This wasn't what I hoped to find but this will explains my problem and helps me get on with my work.

Comment: @Heribert Schnackenwurst : you're welcome.